# Angular Tooltip showing on the wrong Ag-Grid cell

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I am using **Ag-grid** to generate a table, I have cell validation which checks the value of the cell. On wrong value I want to show a **tooltip**. I've managed to do all of this, except that the **Tooltip doesn't show on the cell with the wrong input but on the first cell to the right and only there.**

[image]

My code

```
data.map(object => {
        Object
          .keys(object)
          .map(key => {
            let mappedColumn = {
              headerName: key,
              field: key,
              hide: this.configurationSettings.hide,
              cellRenderer: "cellEditorComponent",    
              pinned: null,             
              inputType: this.inputType,
              cellStyle: (event) => { return this.cellValidation(event) },
              tooltip: (event) => { return this.setErrorMessage(event) }
            }
        columnDefinitions.push(mappedColumn);

cellValidation(param: any) {
    this.isValid=true;
    if (param && param.node && !param.node.lastChild && this.validateInput && !this.validateInput.test(param.value))
    {
      this.isValid = false;
      return { 'background-color': 'rgb(255, 230, 230)', 'border-color': 'red', 'font-weight': 'normal'    }
        }else if (param && param.node && param.node.lastChild && param.node.data["Consultant"] == "Planned hours")
        {
          return {'font-weight': 'bold'};
        }
}

     setErrorMessage(param: any) {
        //if (param && this.cellValidation(param) != null)
        if (!this.isValid) { 
          return this.errorMessage; 
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't know why exactly, but this solves the issue :

```
 setErrorMessage(param: any) {
    if (param && this.cellValidation(param) != null && !this.isValid)
    { return this.errorMessage;}}
```